# JPA Join table generated with primary keys instead of foreign keys

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Well I have a OneToMany unidirectionnal relationship between `TeamEntity` and `ContestTypeEntity`.

So in my `TeamEntity` I have the following :

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = ContestTypeEntity.class)
@JoinTable(name="team_contest_type")
private Set<ContestTypeEntity> contestTypes = new HashSet<>();
```

`ContestTypeEntity` doesn't know about the relation.

Normally, JPA should generate a join table `team_contest_type` with two foreign keys : `team_entity_id` and `contest_types_id`.

But in the join table actually generated, those are primary keys, so I'm not able to insert not unique values... And that's what I want to do.
How can I fix this?

Comment: You want to insert not unique  value in jointable  ? Jpa automatic use primary key as foriegn key of join table

Comment: The join table purpose is to provide unique pairs `(team_entity_id, contest_types_id)`. Why do you want to "fix" this?

Comment: The Team can be linked to several ContestType and ContestType can have several Teams; so the result would be non unique pairs. I don't know how to do it ^^'

Comment: Pair is always unique, like (1,1),(1,2),(2,1) all are okay but again (1,1) not okay. And it's seems manytomany relation use @ManyToMany

Comment: I want pairs like that (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2). Pairs will be unique but ids can be used more than one time

Comment: Use @ManyToMany on contestTypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so a ManyToMany relation with a Set on both sides solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use *@JoinColumn* instead of *@JoinTable*. And remember that when working with JPA/Hibernate/ORM you are working with object references, not with table keys.
This can help you not to use unidirectional with OneToMany:
https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/#Don8217t_use_unidirectional_one-to-many_associations

Comment: The @JoinColumn created a column in contest_type with the ID of the team. But one ContestType can have several Teams, so that's not what I want